# Multiple click events being added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, click

So I have a weird problem. I have an `<a/>` tag that I am applying a click event to using `jQuery.on()`. Here is where the problem happens. Every time I click on the `<a/>` tag, it seems that it adds another click event to the tag.

So I have an a tag like:

```
<a href="#" id="next-arrow" class="nav-arrows inactive"></a>
```

And here is my JS.

```
$('body').on('click', '#next-arrow', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('body').addClass('loading-cursor');
        document.location.hash=step_names[current_step];
        $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $('#tools').append(loader);
        $('#tools').find('.loader-outer').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                //Do some stuff here once the loader is faded in
        }); //End loader FadeIn()
    }   
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

That function is within a `$(function() {});`

Any idea one what might be happening? I have a bunch of JS code for other elements that aren't related. However, if someone has an idea, and would like some other code up, let me know.

Thanks

PS. I would just like to add, that I went to make a jsFiddle thing to try and replicate, but I can't replicate it. So I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: Ok. It's being bound to the `body`, but only being fired when the use clicked on the specified `a` tag. This method replaces jquery.live as of jQuery 1.7... Correct?

Comment: Correct. Try using `return false` instead of `e.preventDefault();`. Returning `false` from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: What browser are you using during development? Just noticed while working on another question that selecting `body` with jQuery is returning null. Not sure why yet (is body considered a node in the DOM?) but to be on the safe side, you might want to use the widely-accepted `$(document)` or move to an even closer ancestor if possible.

Comment: Could you describe what happens (that shouldn't) in more detail?

Comment: I'm using Safari on Mac. It's also happening on Chrome. I haven't tested other browser as of yet. I originally used `$(document)` but have been changed to $(`body`) because it's the closest ancestor.

Comment: can you make it direct? 
`$("#next-arrow").click(function(){/*do something here*/});`

Comment: That's the darndest thing... I could've sworn body wasn't working in the fiddle I tried, but just revisited and it's working after all. Carry on. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Start Note:** Do I add this answer here, or just mention in a comment?

So I figured out the problem. I was appending the loader, and then fading in the loader using a class selector, then fading the loader out, but not removing the element from the DOM.

So then the next time I called the function, it was appending the loader, fading it two loaders, and then for each loader, running the middle function, and so forth...

So, once I loaded everything, I just removed the loader element from the DOM, and all is happy again.

Thanks for the help anyway... I did learn a thing or two more about jQuery during my research...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a selector which explicitly selentcs the `ID` of the `<a>` tag. Something like

```
$('#next-arrow').bind('click', function (e){
    .
    .
    .
});
```

or if that has the same issue, just unbind the click event from the `<a>` tag using `.unbind('click')` before binding it.